# can't post derived class as a parameter from angular code while Making a call to .NET Core Web API Controller that has Parameter of Base Type

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

My Web API method expects a parameter of a  `SomeObject` which has property of  `BaseObj`. Clients are expected to pass in an object (`SomeObject`) which has property of a derived type (`DerivedObj` for example).

I'm sending object via angular service.

```
// web api side
// The base and derived types
public class BaseObj { public virtual string Text { get; set; } }
public class DerivedObj: BaseObj  { public override string Text { get; set; } }
public class SomeObject{
public BaseObj prop{get;set;}
}

// The API controller

public class TestApiController : ApiController
{
[HttpPost("ObjInsert")]
public void ObjInsert(SomeObject someObj)
{ } 
}


//Angular side I have models with same hierarchy

save() { 
    this.someService.objInsert(this.someObject).subscribe
      (
         //some code
      );
  }
```

The problem is that the obj parameter property received by the API method is truly of type `BaseObj`, not `DerivedObj`.
Derived Object is visible in angular side while sending save request.

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: Generally speaking, you don’t want base/derived classes nor any sort of class hierarchy in your parameters. I recommend redesigning to use POCOs in your API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined `SomeObject` as having a property of type `BaseObj`.  So, when the framework gets the JSON for the HTTP request, it knows nothing of your derived class, nor would it expect to. You've defined a class that uses the `BaseObj` type, so that's what it's going to deserialize on the C# side.

I assume the difference between your classes on the C# side is some sort of behavioral aspect. You have a couple of options to deal with this:

1. Use partial classes on the C# side, and extend them with the behavior you need.
2. Use extension methods to add the behavior to a non-polymorphic base class.

It is a best practice to define straight data transfer classes to handle the movement of data within an API. This means your classes should be free from behavior and any type of inheritance structure. All data transfer objects should be standalone and not depend upon other classes for part of their structure. This may drive you crazy at first, but you'll appreciate it as you transition from development to maintenance.